# Why is my email stuck in Outlook's outbox if I try to view it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I don't know if it's a bug with Outlook 2010, but if I schedule a mail by puting a time and date for it to go at a later time and then review the mail in any way it will not be sent.

I can't change the date, I can't open the outbox or else the mail will be stuck there.

Is this the normal behaviour ? Is there any way I can change the settings in a mail in my outbox or at least open it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These articles suggest this is normal behavior when a message in your Outbox is marked as read before it is sent.

The first article suggests applications and addins that might make this problem more likely to occur. Otherwise, either avoid viewing your Outbox, hide the preview pane when viewing the Outbox if it is currently shown, and try marking the message as unread before you return to your Inbox.

http://slipstick.com/problems/after-viewing-outlooks-outbox-the-messages-in-it-wont-send/

http://slipstick.com/problems/common-problems-that-cause-email-to-stay-in-the-outbox/

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was Symantec endpoint protection add-in witch was the culprit. I disabled it in File tab, Options, Add-ins and then COM add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible feature of Outlook that has caused me untold headaches of people never receiving an email. The [quickest fix](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mail-in-outbox-not-sending-if-ive-read-edited-it/a974ff1b-7105-471f-b26f-1454aa360fd8) is to move the message to another folder (say a 'test' folder you create just for this nonsense bug) and then send it from there. It should work at this point.